# Python - Global array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to do:

```
x = []
def func():
   for y in range(0,5):
       x.append(y)

def func2():
   for i in range(0, 5):
       print x[i]
```

And I get the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

How can I put the global x array? And access in the func2 the value of the x array.

Comment: Note that your codes does not run. There is no `y` defined, and you need to put parentheses `()` after the function's declaration (`def func():`).

Comment: This code is incomplete, as well as being syntactically invalid.. How do you call func and func2? Are you actually appending five items to x?

Comment: I suppose this happens at `print x[i]`?! Well, are there 5 elements in the array...!?

Comment: I change the code. I made an example only to know how to access a global x array.

Comment: how many times do you call `func()`? at least 5 or otherwise you will get an index error....¿may it be the problem?

Comment: You *are* accessing the global array. You just don't seem to have five elements in it. And you still haven't shown code that actually gives the error when you run it.

Comment: It's only an example. But i have 5 elements in the array. I have only the problem of the global.

Comment: make sure you are calling `func()` before you call `func2()`

Comment: If it was a `global` problem you'd see a different error message. All signs point to simply not having 5 elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you declared `func()` sooner than `func2()`

What matter is that you should call `func()` before `func2()`, otherwise you will get the error, because your array is still empty.

So this:

```
x = []
def func():
    for y in range(0,5):
        x.append(y)

def func2():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print x[i]
func()
func2()
```

WORKS!

But this:

```
x = []
def func():
    for y in range(0,5):
        x.append(y)

def func2():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print x[i]
func2()
func()
```

DOES NOT!

Answer (score 4):

You will get that error if you call `func2` before calling `func`

```
>>> x=[]
>>> func2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in func2
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> func()
>>> func2()
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

List index out of bound is because you have no elements in the list when you call func2().

since you are looping over a range of range(0,5) initialize the list with `x = [0] * 5`

```
x = []
def func():
   for y in range(0,5):
       x.append(y)

def func2():
   for i in range(0, 5):
       print x[i]

func()
func2()
```

if you call func2() without actually including elements with your function func(), obviously `print x[i]` will raise Index Out of Bound exception because the list is empty.

Comment: *"No"* or **less than 5**.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for the original question that looked like this:

```
x = []

def func():
    y = 2
    x.append(y)

def func2():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print(x[i])
```

Call `func` 5 times and it works:

```
for n in range(5):
    func()

func2()
```

Output:

```
2
2
2
2
2
```

Your list `x` was still empty. Calling `func` appends `2`.  The whole code is not really useful but it demonstrates how it works.